# onCharacteristicChanged is not callBack in Android 5.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

It is callback that 'onCharacteristicChanged' in Android 4.3 but it is not call in Android 5.0 above. 'WriteCharacteristic' and 'setCharaceristicNotification' is successful and 'onCharacteristicWrite' callback is successful yet.Why it is not call in Android5.0 or Android 6.0.

This is my notification code:

```
private void notification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic, String tag) {
    boolean success = mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
    if (success) {
        for (BluetoothGattDescriptor dp : gattCharacteristic.getDescriptors()) {
            if (dp != null) {
                if ((gattCharacteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) {
                    dp.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                    Log.i(TAG,"notification NOTIFICATION value = "+ Arrays.toString(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE));
                } else if ((gattCharacteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0) {
                    dp.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                    Log.i(TAG,"notification INDICATION value = "+ Arrays.toString(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE));

                }
                mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(dp);
                Log.i(TAG, tag + " notification successful");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"BluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(dp)" is failed, and it is a asynchronous thread. It is stop to write descriptor when the thread busy. So I write descriptor one by one. It's ok.